# How to add a videojs plugin on React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I created a functional React component to render a videojs player which works really well, but now I'm trying to add a plugin (in this case I'm trying with videojs-preview: https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-preview) and it fails.
Here is my component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import preview from 'videojs-preview';

const Player = (props) => {
  const [videoEl, setVideoEl] = useState(null);
  const onVideo = useCallback((el) => {
    setVideoEl(el);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoEl == null) return;
    videojs.registerPlugin('videojs-preview', preview);
    videojs(videoEl, { ...props }, () => {
      videojs.preview();
    });
  }, [props, videoEl]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={onVideo} className="video-js vjs-big-play-centered mt-10" playsInline crossOrigin="anonymous" height={630} autoPlay />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

The error I'm getting is: TypeError: video_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...).preview is not a function

Comment: Have you tried barrel import? => `import * as preview from 'videojs-preview';` . But the module does not look maintained, when using it in production your security could suffer.. For video related stuff I recommend using `react-player`  module.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin registers itself so `videojs.registerPlugin()` is not needed.

Just import as `import 'videojs-preview';`, and init the plugin on the player instance rather than `videojs`.

```js
const player = (playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
  player.preview();
}));
```

An example with a different plugin but the same principle is at https://codesandbox.io/s/video-js-seek-buttons-react-vl7ux